# How to make quick edits to images uploaded to media library

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, photoshop, media-library

When I have images uploaded to Wordpress, there is no way for me to flexibly edit these images. For example, let's say I want to add a colored overlay over an image that has been uploaded to Wordpress. For me to do this, I have to add the overlay to the image, then upload the new modified image to Wordpress. When I am developing a non-Wordpress site, however, all I have to do is link to the photo in the CSS, then using the Image Assets generator, the linked image is changed on the fly. This saves me from having to re-upload photos every time I make a change.

Is there any Photoshop script or plugin, or just a method in general for editing photos without having to re-upload them to Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any script out there that I know of, but if you have access to the wordpress uploads directory via an ftp client, you can edit the originally uploaded file and then use a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to update the smaller and automatically generated images.